# Delay deploying WAR in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat7, war

While a WAR files is being copied to be deployed, the deployment in Tomcat is triggered as soon as the file changes. But in mot of the cases it would not be complete yet, so you can get the following error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Is there any way to configure hot-deployment in Tomcat to await some time or until the size of the file is stabilized?